# check if two specific characters are together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a form following is my code
**JQuery:**

```
var x = $('.email').val() //fetching the value of input box
```

**Regex:**

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    var valid = emailReg.test(email);
    if (!valid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

although this function will validate my email, but I want to show a message if user is putting @ and . together.
all I want to check if two characters are coming together... i mean like this

john@.com

so I need a condition in which I can get to know whether both are together or not...please help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, put it in the if statement

```
email.indexOf('@.') == -1
```

Comment: yea it seems a simple index of would take care of this

Answer (score 0):

use can use `.match()` as

```
var str="john@.com";
var n=str.match(/@\./g);
```

it will find **@.** and then run if found

```
if(n)
 // code
```